# Travis CI no output

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

No output has been received in the last 10 minutes, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.

this is my project https://github.com/GinMu/node-test-demo.git

thank you !

Comment: welcome to SO. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build is timing out as `gulp.watch` waits for changes; normally this is fine for local development. This is setup in your gulp build script  as the default task, so the `npm test` command is calling the npm script in your `package.json` and calling just `gulp`.

With your project's `package.json`, try using just the mocha task to run tests. e.g. change your script to :-

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "gulp mocha"
 }
```

The mocha tests should now run without the watchers preventing the build from completing.